# Export Get-Child into a .CSV

Tags: powershell

For some reason when I open the CSV I get just lengths not sure what I am missing.  When I run it without the Pipe into CSV it returns the names.  I just want the name to drop into an either a .txt or .csv

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Tri\Documents\ -Name -Recurse -Force|Export-Csv -Path .\test.csv
```

Comment: the REASON your code fails to do what you want is because you used the `-Name` parameter in your `G-CI` call. [*grin*] that sends _only_ the name of the file, not the usual structured object ... and `Export-CSV` requires a structured object. **_when you send just a plain string object, you get only the properties of that string ... and the only property is the length of that string._**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a simple text file, use
[Out-File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1)
rather than Export-Csv:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Tri\Documents\ -Name -Recurse | Out-File C:\Temp\test.txt -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you so much.